# Loading custom weights for tensorflow layers

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I trained a DNN in theano but due to certain issues, I switched to tensorflow. I converted the weights from theano to tensorflow format. I built up the same architecture in tensorflow as it was in theano. But how do I initialize the weights of the layers with the `weight file` I have on my disk. This is my base architecture:

```
input_layer = keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(224,224,3),input_tensor=features)

# Conv block 1
conv1_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, 
                           filters=64, kernel_size=[3,3], 
                           padding='same', 
                           activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           name='conv1_1')

conv1_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=conv1_1, 
                           filters=64, kernel_size=[3,3], 
                           padding='same', 
                           activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           name='conv1_2')

pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1_2,
                                pool_size=(2,2), 
                                strides=(2,2), 
                                name='pool1')


# Conv block 2
conv2_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, 
                           filters=128, kernel_size=[3,3], 
                           padding='same', 
                           activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           name='conv2_1')

conv2_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=conv2_1, 
                           filters=128, kernel_size=[3,3], 
                           padding='same', 
                           activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           name='conv2_2')

pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2_2,
                                pool_size=(2,2), 
                                strides=(2,2), 
                                name='pool2')

# Conv block 3
conv3_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool2, 
                           filters=256, kernel_size=[3,3], 
                           padding='same', 
                           activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           name='conv3_1')

conv3_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=conv3_1, 
                           filters=256, kernel_size=[3,3], 
                           padding='same', 
                           activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           name='conv3_2')

conv3_3 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=conv3_2, 
                           filters=256, kernel_size=[3,3], 
                           padding='same', 
                           activation=tf.nn.relu,
                           name='conv3_3')

pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3_3,
                                pool_size=(2,2), 
                                strides=(2,2), 
                                name='pool3')
```

How do I load the weights for these layers from the weight file I have on my disk? Please help

Comment: Why not use Keras model for both backends?

Comment: Because there are certain things which are not there in keras right now. Also, not allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different ways to accomplish this. I'd say the easiest way would be to export the weight (parameter) matrices and bias vectors as arrays using `np.savez`

For instance, you can build a dictionary and add the arrays

```
params = {}
...

params['fc1/weights'] = this_weight_matrix
params['fc1/biases'] = this_bias_vector
...

np.savez('model_weights', **params)
```

Then, say you setup your TensorFlow graph; this is an example fully connected layer as a wrapper function:

```
def fc_layer(input_tensor, n_output_units, name,
             activation_fn=None, seed=None,
             weight_params=None, bias_params=None):

    with tf.variable_scope(name):

        if weight_params is not None:
            weights = tf.Variable(weight_params, name='weights',
                                  dtype=tf.float32)
        else:
            weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
                shape=[input_tensor.get_shape().as_list()[-1], n_output_units],
                    mean=0.0,
                    stddev=0.1,
                    dtype=tf.float32,
                    seed=seed),
                name='weights',)

        if bias_params is not None:
            biases = tf.Variable(bias_params, name='biases', 
                                 dtype=tf.float32)

        else:
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[n_output_units]),
                                 name='biases', 
                                 dtype=tf.float32)

        act = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights) + biases

        if activation_fn is not None:
            act = activation_fn(act)

    return act
```

Next, say you load the parameters you saved to disk back into a Python session:

```
param_dict = np.load('model_weigths.npz')
```

Then, when you setup your actual graph (using the previous wrapper function), you would do it as follows:

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    fc1 = fc_layer(input_tensor=tf_x, 
                   n_output_units=n_hidden_1, 
                   name='fc1',
                   weight_params=fixed_params['fc1/weights'], 
                   bias_params=fixed_params['fc1/biases'],
                   activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
...
```

Comment: Okay that's one way. Waht about if I am using the `tf.layers` api?. Does passing the weights to the `kernel_initializer` work the same way?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Haven't used the tf.layers API much and haven't tried to provide custom weights through the initializers. You probably need to set up a custom initializer class with `__init__`, `__call__`, and `get_config` methods. For an example see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L318